# Wine won't let me run League of Legends

Tags: wine

The wine windows crashes right away after it opens. (I see the blue screen of the Wine virtual environment, but after a few seconds it gets shut without saying anything.)

Comment: Try using PlayOnLinux. It selects the best Wine version for a game and installs it.

Comment: I'm using it, and I've been following the guide. I had no problems till that point..

Comment: For me, it's working using LXDE, but not with Unity/GNOME. Maybe you could try installing LXDE additionally (not lubuntu-desktop but lxde-core) and do the complete PoL virtual drive setup from scratch...

Comment: If you launch it from the command line, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked using LXDE instead of Unity.
Install it with the command `sudo apt-get install lxde-core` and on your next login you should be able to select the desktop environment.

Note that you might have to reinstall LoL while running LXDE. And never execute it in Unity again. I don't know why, but it didn't work for me any more after I tried to.